# Sent ether to Etc instead of Eth on Nano s

Tags: ledger-nano-s

Hi I sent Ether to Etc instead of Eth on ledger Nano s, and its not showed up, I've confirmed  it was sent(Ehterscan) i went to Myetherwallet, connected my Nano to search for it, using more address, still no sign of transfer or address used, please help

Answer (score 0):

Etc and Eth are on different chain. So of course, it's not going to work.
Your money is lost.

Comment: I followed this link, but couldn't see my transfer or address, any ideas guy and girls